# Azure Functions bindings using V4 model node.js - http in and service bus out

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azureservicebus

My azure function accepts a HTTP request and generates a message that is posted to a service bus topic.  It's working, but the message body is going back to the http requester.

What I want is for the httpRequest to get a 200 response with an empty body and the service bus topic message to contain the response.  I can't seem to separate them.

I think the clue rests in the function options object return property (ref: [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=typescript%2Clinux%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4)) but I can't seem to get this working.

```
export async function ediReprocessEvent(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
context.log(`ediReprocessEvent function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
try {
    let body = await request.json() as IReprocessRequest;
    let result = await ediDocEvent(body, context);
    return {
        status: 200,
        body: result,
    };
} catch (err:any) {
    return {
        status: 500,
        body: err.message,
    };
}
```

}

```
app.http('ediReprocessEvent', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: ediReprocessEvent,
    return: output.serviceBusTopic({
        topicName: 'MyTopic',
        connection: 'MyConnection',
    }),      
});
```

Comment: please share the details of what type of Output you are getting in http response and what type of message is displayed in service bus. what type of output you are expecting in service bus and http response in text format.

Comment: @pavan - think that's covered in above - the output to both bindings is the same - a json object containing status and body properties.  I want a status only returned to http and the result string as the message body

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all it takes is a good sleep.

The following results in a 204 returned to the caller and the message posted to the topic.

```
export async function ediReprocessEvent(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
        context.log(`ediReprocessEvent function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        try {
            let body = await request.json() as IReprocessRequest;
            let result = await ediDocEvent(body, context);
            context.extraOutputs.set(topicOutput, result)
            return;
        } catch (err:any) {
            return {
                status: 500,
                body: err.message,
            };
        }
    }
    const topicOutput = output.serviceBusTopic({
        topicName: 'normalised-edi-document-prod',
        connection: 'UFProd_SERVICEBUSTOPIC',
    });

app.http('ediReprocessEvent', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: ediReprocessEvent,
    extraOutputs: [topicOutput]
});
```